# What's the difference between the next situations

Tags: java, exception, throwable

Please, tell me difference between the next situations :

```
public class Test {
    private static < T extends Throwable > void doThrow(Throwable ex) throws T {
        throw (T) ex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThrow(new Exception()); //it's ok
    }
}
```

There is no compilation error in this case

AND

```
public class Test {
    private static < T extends Throwable > void doThrow(Throwable ex) throws Throwable {
        throw (T) ex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThrow(new Exception()); //unhandled exception
    }
}
```

There is compilation error

Comment: What does the compilation error say?

Comment: It's advised to not throw a Throwable. This is because Throwable contains both the Exception and Error class. You don't want to handle an Error in your code. Throws Exception is what you probably want.

Comment: @ЛешаПакки Based on your example cause of compilation error has nothing to do with the body of the method so I simplified your example to skip it and focus on main difference which is `throws T` vs `throws Throwable`. If you don't agree with that change let me know so I can revert it.

Comment: I could swear the question looked completely different the last time I saw it. And both methods had `<T extends Throwable>`. It was also pretty understandable. (Not saying it's worse now.)

Comment: @akuzminykh True, in original version second case also contained `<T extends Throwable>` in method declaration but since `T` isn't used there in `throws` leaving it in example IMO would only add unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Sorry i did a rollback, my intention is to maintain the code in different blocks rather than in same block, but the tittle now is like meaningless @Pshemo

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, title was the reason why I *started* editing, but I don't want to get involved in rollback-war. OP should decide which version (s)he prefers.

Comment: @akuzminykh "you also basically threw the initial state out of the window and rewrote it" yes, that was to make it simpler since removed parts ware irrelevant to error which OP is asking about. My rationale is: we see two versions of *same class* where only difference is `throws T` vs `throws Throwable` in `doThrow` method. In main method compiler doesn't care if/when method throws exception (it can also never throw it), so method body can also be removed from this example, making `<T extends Throwable>` irrelevant for second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it right now in the question, makes it works because `T` is inferred to be a `RuntimeException`( I remember this because of `@SneakyThrows`):

```
private static < T extends Throwable > void doThrow(Throwable ex) throws T {
     throw (T) ex;
}
```

Basically the `JLS` says that if you declare a method that has `throws XXX`, where the upper bound of `XXX` is `Exception` or `Throwable`, the `XXX` is inferred to a `RuntimeException`.